# Update property value in Neo4j on import

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following code for importing data in CSV. The data is of the form **A-[:LIKES {times: x}]-B** where x is a number. However when importing, I am stuck on how to update the value of times if the relationship is found again. There seems to be a **SET** function that allows you to do so, but I can't get to place it properly.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/gvanjoic/file.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line[0]})
WITH line, n
MERGE (m:B {ID : line[1]})
WITH m,n
MERGE (n)-[:LIKES]->(m);
```

Kindly help me update the value of of the property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

You should be able to do this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/gvanjoic/file.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line[0]})
WITH line, n
MERGE (m:B {ID : line[1]})
WITH m,n
MERGE (n)-[rel:LIKES]->(m)
ON CREATE SET rel.times = (CASE WHEN rel.times IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rel.times END) + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can update the values accordingly provided the nodes are already present. However I can't do so when some nodes/relationship are encountered for the first time. See [EDIT]  above

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it initializes the `times` property if it does not already exist.